# How to get hash table key which has specific value?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having a hash table where Keys are being used based on value.

For ex.

```
    $ComponentTobeBuild=@{"ComponentNameX"="True";
                          "ComponentNameXyz"="False";
                          "SomeComponent"="False"}
```

I would like to get the keys which are having values True. (I will pass the key to some other script as parameter).

I was trying like that , But i think some where i am missing as it is not listing the keys.

```
$($ComponentToBuild.Keys) | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq "True" }
```

How to get the component Name which are having denoted as True? Also i would like to know whether hash table is a wise choice for this kind of work. Because I thought that Hash table will be mainly be used for processing the values.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hi this should work for what you want.

```
$ComponentTobeBuild=@{"ComponentNameX"="Test";
                          "ComponentNameXyz"="False";
                          "SomeComponent"="False"}                    

Foreach ($Key in ($ComponentTobeBuild.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq "Test"}))
{$Key.name}
```

Comment: This script is trying to get values ,actually i was trying get keys. But putting this also doesn't work. $ComponentTobeBuild.Keys| Where-Object { $_ -eq "True" }

Comment: O ok sorry i changed the code check if it works now . ps copy the complete code and give it a try, you could put code in the "{$Key.name}" section to put all the keys that have a value of test in to another hash table if you like

Comment: I like this answer as it's using Name property of GetEnumerator(), but I don't like mixing of foreach() and pipe. Either put the Where-Object inside foreach statement as if(), or use just pipe: `$ComponentTobeBuild.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq "Test"} | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}`

Comment: You can also use `$Key.Key` as `Name` is an alias property.

Answer (score 25):

```
$ComponentTobeBuild.GetEnumerator() | ? { $_.Value -eq "True" }
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old, but I saw this on my search for an other problem and wondered why you bother with Enumerators. Just build the code exactly as the question in real language:

Give me all keys, where the value is 'True'.

```
$ComponentTobeBuild.Keys | ? { $ComponentTobeBuild[$_] -eq 'True'  }
```

For sake of consistency I would encapsulate that in `@()` to get an Array even if there is just one or no result.

As for the Solution the asker had, the problem is that `$_` is a String and `.Value` is not the value of the key. It simply doesn't exist in a String. You have to get the value of the hashtable with `$_` as Key in order to compare it.

Comment: This may cause unexpected behavior when the collection has multiple entries with the same key...

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ in Powershell you cannot create hastable with non-unique keys

Comment: @maozim I think we are using the term hashtable wrongly, since we are using a dictionary/map datastructure in the question. Hashtables in .net can have collisions, and will use a linked list to store multiple items under the same hashcode. A hashtable is all about retrieval by object. A dictionary uses unique keys

Comment: (@{}).GetType().Fullname is System.Collections.Hashtable

Answer (score 8):

The problem with filtering Hashtables in PowerShell is that you can't iterate over the Key-Value pairs.

Let's say you have some collection:

```
$collection = @{ 
    a = 'A'; 
    b = 'B'; 
    c = 'C'; 
    d = 'D'; 
    e = 'E';
    ...
}
```

You would expect to be able to use

```
$results = $collection | Where-Object { $_.Key -in ('a', 'b', 'd') }
```

in PowerShell, but that's not possible.

Therefore you have fall back to using the enumerator:

```
$results = $collection.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Key -in ('a', 'b', 'd') }
$results

Name                           Value
----                           -----
d                              D
b                              B
a                              A
```

Comment: Can anyone provide a rationale why .keys cannot be iterated over or indexed like other collections?  Its type is Hashtable+keyCollection, which at least implies it's a kind of collection.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the `Dictionary.Keys`' `Where` method which returns all elements where a condition holds true. That condition could be a lambda asserting that the tested key `$_` relates to a `"True"` value in the dictionary.

```
$ComponentTobeBuild=@{"ComponentNameX"="True";
                      "ComponentNameXyz"="False";
                      "SomeComponent"="False"}
$ComponentTobeBuild.Keys.Where({$ComponentTobeBuild[$_] -eq "True"})
# -> @("ComponentNameX")
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and tidiest) way I found to do this was as follows:

```
$ComponentToBuild.where{$_.Keys -match 'True'}
```

Then get just the bits you need

```
$ComponentToBuild.where{$_.Keys -match 'True'} | select Field1,Field2,Field99
```

etc

Comment: You're filtering on the keys rather than values, this wouldn't work