# How do I retrieve a HashTable key from a value?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell HashTable that contains a set of key-value pairs (naturally). All of the HashTable values are unique.

I would like to retrieve a HashTable key, based on a value that I specify, using PowerShell.

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357654/how-to-get-hash-table-key-which-has-specific-value) But under this question, @Vadim provided the only clean and comprehensive Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell 4.0's Where method syntax to achieve this. The Where method accepts a PowerShell `ScriptBlock` to find objects matching the specified criteria. We can iterate over the HashTable keys and find a key that contains the desired value.

In case you do have a scenario where you have duplicate HashTable **values**, you can optionally specify a second parameter, of type `WhereOperatorSelectionMode`, that specifies which objects should be returned by the call to the Where method. By specifying `First` for the second method parameter, we can ensure that only a single HashTable key is ever returned.

All of the supported values for the second parameter are as follows:

- Default
- First
- Last
- SkipUntil
- Until
- Split

---

```
$HashTable = @{
    1 = 10;
    2 = 20;
    3 = 30;
}

$Val = 30;
$HashTable.Keys.Where({ $HashTable[$PSItem] -eq $Val; }, [System.Management.Automation.WhereOperatorSelectionMode]::First);
```

Answer (score 4):

Another options:

- to iterate over the HashTable keys and find a key that contains the
  value:
   `$HashTable.Keys |? { $HashTable[$_] -eq $Val }`
- to iterate using `GetEnumerator()` function:

  `$HashTable.GetEnumerator() | ?{ $_.Value -eq $Val } | %{ $_.Key }`